# why I getting diffrent result between Emacs org and clion to runing the same perl code?

Tags: org-mode

1.In clion:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
my $todlist="GOTO  /  -71.42857,  -16.00000,  -49.48717,-0.866025, 0.000000,-0.500000";
my @do = split( /\/|,|\s/, $todlist);
my @str=round_num03(@do);
print(@str);
#foreach my $element (@str) {
#    print ($element);
#}
sub round_num03{
    foreach (@_) {
        if ( looks_like_number($_) )
        {
            $_ = sprintf( "|%.3f", $_);
        }
    }
    return @_;
}
```

I get result:GOTO|-71.429|-16.000|-49.487|-0.866|0.000|-0.500

2.In my emaces org mode,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC perl  :results value :exports results both
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
my $todlist="GOTO  /  -71.42857,  -16.00000,  -49.48717,-0.866025, 0.000000,-0.500000";
my @do = split( /\/|,|\s/, $todlist);
my @str=round_num03(@do);
#print(@str);
#foreach my $element (@str) {
#    print ($element);
#}
return @str;
sub round_num03{
    foreach (@_) {
        if ( looks_like_number($_) )
        {
            $_ = sprintf( "|%.3f", $_);
        }
    }
    return @_;
}
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 16
```

The result is 16,may be the size of the array.why? And how to return the string .

Comment: Have you tried tangling the code and looking at the diff between the tangled code and your "code". My guess is that there is a difference between both. If not, you may want to check a difference between interpreters

Comment: I have resolve it ,just use *return "@str"* ,and return the whole string.

Comment: Then you hould create a proper solution and accep it for the comunnity's sake

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it .Use

```
return "@str"
```

to replace

```
return @str
```

Press C-c C-c,It is return the string.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC perl  :results value :exports results both
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
my $todlist="GOTO  /  -71.42857,  -16.00000,  -49.48717,-0.866025, 0.000000,-0.500000";
my @do = split( /\/|,|\s/, $todlist);
my @str=&round_num03(@do);
return "the reslut is："."@str";
sub round_num03{
    foreach (@_) {
        if ( looks_like_number($_) )
        {
            $_ = sprintf( "|%.3f", $_);
        }
    }
    return @_;
}
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| the reslut is：GOTO | -71.429 | -16.0 | -49.487 | -0.866 | 0.0 | -0.5 |
```